# Lightdm not working at all since bumblebee install!

Tags: 12.10, boot-failure, lightdm, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I'm relatively new to Ubuntu, so please excuse me if my question is stupid...

So a few weeks ago, I bought a Gigabyte U2442N with Optimus Graphics (a 640M and a HD4000). I installed the stable release of Quantal relatively new at the time, and then, after some research, found out that I needed to install Bumblebee for Optimus to work. But after installation, Ubuntu was hanging on boot (just a black screen with a flashing prompt).

I figured it must be the Display Manager, so after some time, I gave up and just installed GDM, which works just fine. But still, I like LightDM with the Unity Greeter much better, so I tried everything to get LightDM to work: I used different Nvidia PPAs and tried solutions suggested to similar problems, but nothing helped.

Is this maybe a known bug? Or did I just do something wrong?

I appreciate any help...

Comment: It would be great if you could report the issue here: https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Reporting-Issues